# named routes from string with object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, methods, routes

I am looking to create a named route from a string and pass an object into it

I am rendering a partial with a local "resource"

ie. `render :partial => "listing", :locals => {:resource => @resource}`

inside _listing.html.haml i am using the self.send method

```
self.send("#{resource.class.to_s.downcase}_path()")
```

this works just fine and creates the resources named route
ie. article_path()

but this route needs an object passed in the route
ie. article_path(article)

i am trying this

```
self.send("#{resource.class.to_s.downcase}_path("+resource+")")
```

and get the error
can't convert Article into String

any suggestions?

Comment: after alot of tinkering i found the answer was simple enough.

the fix was to make it comma seperated

_listing.html.haml

    - resource_path = "#{resource.class.to_s.downcase}_path"
    = link_to resource.title, send(resource_path, resource)

Hope this helps anyone struggling with the same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should pass the arguments like this :

```
self.send("#{resource.class.to_s.downcase}_path", resource)
```

Comment: @Ben I didn't see your comment, glad you figured it out by your own.

Comment: I'd use the following instead: `self.send("#{resource.class.to_s.underscore}_path", resource)` It will work in the event that your class is more than one word e.g. `FooBar -> foo_bar`